# Return type of a Pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, gige-sdk

In the GigE SDK C++, the specification notes the definition of GetDataPointer() as follows:

```
PvUInt8 * PvBuffer::GetDataPointer  (   )   
Get the buffer's data pointer. 
Const version.
Returns:
A pointer to the memory pointer.
```

I used this function in my program like this (pl see last line):

```
PvBuffer * lBuffer = new PvBuffer();
// Create the Data (buffers are created as images, GetImage() is valid on a fresh buffer)
lBuffer->GetImage()->Alloc( 1224, 1029, PvPixelMono8 );
PvUInt8 *lDataBuffer = lBuffer->GetDataPointer(); //use in actual code
```

The question is about PvUInt8; looking at the definition, is this the type of the data in the Buffer or that of the pointer which can be 4bytes (on 32 bit machine)or 8 bytes(on 64 bit machine) always.

Comment: I *think* the documentation is trying to say "A pointer to the memory buffer", i.e. "pointer to pointer" is a typo.

Comment: PvUInt8 is an Unsigned Int which is 8 bits wide. The "P" in "Pv" does not mean "Pointer" - it's an SDK-wide prefix. The buffer contains `PvUInt8`s.

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided, `PvUInt8` appears to be an alias of `unsigned char` (a.k.a. "a byte").  This means that `PvUInt8 *` is simply a byte pointer.  `sizeof(PvUInt8)` should be `1`, and `sizeof(PvUInt8 *)` should be the native size of a pointer in the execution environment (e.g. 4 on 32-bit system, 8 on 64-bit system, etc.).